# rails auto-include libraries issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want Rails to auto-include all libraries in my lib directory.

This my current configuration in config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

However, Rails will only include some of the libraries not all.

Is it maybe because library has 2 uppercases in the module name such as ModuleName?

If not, what else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: Try run `rails console` and call your module name. For ensure that your module are not load.